# Mirth Custom Web Service Method

Tags: java, mirth, mirth-connect

I was following mirth tutorials link : http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Creating+a+custom+Web+Service+in+Mirth+Connect+3.0.1

My current mirth version is 3.5.x . Even downloaded donkey-server.jar and donkey-client.jar from mirth library. But when I import it I dont see the AcceptMessage and WebServiceReceiver class being resolved. When I verified in the jars the path com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws is not present.

Please let me which jar to be used to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes are in extensions/ws/ws-server.jar. You can add that to the classpath (with -cp) when compiling your code. More information here: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/How+to+create+and+invoke+custom+Java+code+in+Mirth+Connect